# Print results of re.search as a CSV string

Tags: python, regex, list, csv, regex-group

I'm writing a script to parse out lines of interest from a log. It is working well except for printing the lines. I have a parameterized regex that I use in an `re.search`, which returns my results. I can print them individually or by looping through the list.

My problem is that for each match, I want to print a CSV line, basically each value in quotes with a comma between (and no comma on the end of the line). Is there an easy way to do this?

I have this:

```
   if lineMatch:
      for capturedToken in lineMatch.groups():
        #print capturedToken
```

Using Python 2.7 how would I print as a CSV line (followed by a new line)?

I've tried print/end but from what I understand that is only Python 3.x - every variation I tried gave me syntax errors. I'm sure there's a cool Pythonic way to print the values from the linematch group as a comma separated list; I just don't seem to be able to find it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
if lineMatch:
    print(', '.join(['"{}"'.format(t) for t in lineMatch.groups()]))
```

Usage:

```
>>> m = re.search('(\d{4})-(\S+)', "1995-jun")
>>> print ', '.join(['"{}"'.format(i) for i in m.groups()])
"1995", "jun"
```

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiosity why is the comma at the beginning of the print and the quotes as delimiters within the join? I like the results, I'm just curious as to why there isn't a comma at the beginning of my line, would changing '"{}"' to '"{}",' achieve the same result?

Comment: @Chris `'somestr'.join(iterable)` concatenates all the strings in `iterable` together, using `somestr` as a separator between each element. So for an iterable with length n, it creates `iterable[0] + somestr + iterable[1] + ... + somestr + iterable[n]`. So you don't get a trailing `somestr` (`', '`, in your case). Appending a comma to each element inside the join, like I did with the double-quotes, would add a trailing comma to the last element, which (I assume) isn't what you want to happen. If you do want that, you can use `''.join(['"{}",'.format(i) for i in m.groups()])`.

Comment: Thanks dano, even better than it working is knowing how and why it is working, I appreciate the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Use join method from strings like this:

```
print ",".join(lineMatch.groups())
```